# When textbook has any value then automatically drop-down option will selected

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

When textbox has any value then how to automatically drop-down option will selected?

For Example :

***This is my drop down***

```
<option>pick a color</option>  
<option value="red">RED</option>
<option value="blue">BLUE</option>
<option value="others">Green</option>
```

***This is text box :***

```
<input type="text" name="color" id="color" />
```

***Question***

If any type value is fill in text box, how to select automatically Green in drop down.

Comment: Do you mean irrespective what the text is, as long as there is some text, the  dropdown should select specifically 'Green' as the the option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attach `input` event to the input to track the user change on input then if so select the option you want, check example bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('#color').on('input', function() {
  if($(this).val()!="")
    $('#colors').val("others");
  else
    $('#colors').val("0");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="colors">
  <option value="0">pick a color</option>
  <option value="red">RED</option>
  <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
  <option value="others">Green</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="color" id="color">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using plain JavaScript, you can try this

```
<select id="selection">
<option>pick a color</option>  
<option value="red">RED</option>
<option value="blue">BLUE</option>
<option value="others">Green</option>
</select>


<input type="text" id="color" oninput="myFunction()">

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("selection").value ='others';
}
</script>
```

**Note**: I haven't added the code to handle reseting the selection in case there's no text in the textbox